# Upload a string as file using form post in javascript

Tags: javascript, form-post

I want to fake a file upload without using a file input. The file's content is generated from a string. i.e. I want to post some string to a server with content-type "multipart/form-data".

But the server is with different domain and doesn't support CORS, therefore I could not use XMLHttpRequest. Is it possible to do this using only normal form post?

Comment: With a normal HTML/Form post, that should work. You would need to manually prepare the multipart structure, and send across content-type with proper boundaries. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Actually I want to upload some content as a file to SkyDrive, without using server side code. SkyDrive provides REST api but doesn't support CORS.

Comment: What about targeting your form to a hidden iframe?

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a nice question. In my humble opinion, what you are looking for is not possible for various reasons as listed below:

- You can surely have an HTML form something like this:

  ```
  <form ....>
  <input id="blah" type="input" name="nameblah" ..>
  ...
  </form>
  ```

  But as you would know, you really cant access/modify the "contents" of the file selected. Immediate solution will be to use a hidden field as an alternative and set the `enctype=multipart/form-data`, but for hidden field the browser will not set proper `Content-Disposition` Headers.
- You could have an AJAX call in which you manually build up the entire request body, but that would be a cross domain call, as you have already noted. The usual bypassing techniques apply.

Solution would be to let the server, which serves out the HTML, fulfill the skydrive request for you. In that case you would be uploading the file using HTML form, or javascript. The file will then be "forwarded" to the skydrive server.

In case you are trying via Javascript, be sure to get the `multipart/form-data` format correctly. Here is the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt)